# Selecting monthly data from a range of dates in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to extract monthly data from mysql table from the given range of dates. 
Here is the php code:

```
$start    = (new DateTime('2015-01-28'));
$end      = (new DateTime('2015-12-12'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $mth = $dt->format( "m" );
    $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $mth);
    $mm = $dateObj->format('F');
    $yr =  $dt->format( "Y" );
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(date) = '.$mth.' AND YEAR(date) = '.$yr;
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    $rec = $res->num_rows;
}
```

In doing so, I get the data of the entire months of January and December. How do I ensure that records on or after the chosen dates are selected?

Is there a quick way to know the number of months between two date range?

Comment: What's this got to do with MySQL? Why are you hitting the database at all?

Comment: do you want records between start date and end date ?

Comment: Yes, that too in monthly fashion. If the first date is 2013-10-23, then I need data of the 7 days in that month, not the entire month's.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use this query:

```
Select *
  from table name
 where CAST(dates AS date) BETWEEN '11/2/2014' and '12/5/2014'
```